# How to reduce division with uprounding to integer-arithmetic operations with downrounding if the denominator is not necessarily an integer?

Tags: arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions, arithmetic-functions

Let ∈ℕ₀ be an unknown variable and ∈ℚ₊ be a known constant such that ≥2 and 100 ∈ ℕ₊. (So we can pre-compute anything regarding , e.g., represent 100 as a product of powers of primes.) We would like to compute $\left\lceil\frac{}{}\right\rceil$. At our disposal we have only operations on integers with downrounding: addition, subtraction, integer multiplication, integer division div ($(a\, \mathrm{div}\, b) = \left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor$), and taking the remainder after integer division rem ($(a\,\mathrm{rem}\,b) = a - (a\,\mathrm{div}\,b)b$). If  were an integer, we'd compute (+-1) div  = $\left\lfloor\frac{+-1}{}\right\rfloor$. In our setup,  is NOT known to be an integer — only 100 is. What to do?

Comment: Can't integer division work with rationals?  $a\mid b$ is defined to mean that there exists and integer $n$ so that $b = na$.  There is *no* requirement that $a$ be an integer-- only that $a$ goes into $b$ a whole number of times.  For example $\frac 57\mid 15$ because $15 = 21\times \frac 57$ and $21$ is an integer.  Likewise $\lfloor a/b\rfloor = k\iff kb \le a < (k+1)b$.  There is *no* requirement that $b$ be an integer.

Comment: @fleablood Unfortunately, no, such operation is unavailable.